# Commutative Diagram (Homological Algebra)

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

[image]

I am having a hard time with the following commutative diagram. Mostly, I am not sure how to align the middle row correctly. Currently this is my best attempt.

I cannot get the code to compile upon deleting that unwanted $N_n$ (this is only a sort of dummy so that the code will compile). Also, I can't get the diagram to align nicely as in the picture.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzcd} 
 C_{n+1} \arrow{r} \arrow{dr} & B_n \arrow{d} \arrow{r} & C_n \arrow{r} \arrow{d} &  B_{n-1}  \\ 
 &  A_n \arrow{r} \arrow{d} & A_{n-1} \arrow{r} & N_n  \\
E_{n+1} \arrow{r}  &  D_n \arrow{r} & E_n \arrow{r} &  D_{n-1}    
 \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcom to SE! Please, be so kind and show, what you tried so far.

Comment: Good to see some code. Could you help us by making it so it compiles, too?

Comment: I think that you cannot start with an arrow.

Comment: I could live without the arrows at the beginning.

Comment: I should have said: can you make it a complete *document* rather than can you make it compile. Also good to explain if not-compiling is the problem - then your code should produce the error you want help with when somebody tries to compile it.

Answer (score 5):

```
\arrow{d}
```

means go one-below. So there must be something there.

```
\arrow{dd}
```

means go two-below.

A cell cannot start with an arrow and then have something in it. So

```
\arrow{r} C
```

is no good but

```
\arrow{r} & C
```

is fine.

[image: cd diagram]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  \arrow{r} & C_{n+1} \arrow{dd} \arrow{dr} & & B_n \arrow{dd} \arrow{r} & C_n \arrow{dd} \arrow{dr} & & B_{n-1} \arrow{r} \arrow{dd} & {}\\
  & & A_n \arrow{ur} \arrow{dr} & & & A_{n-1} \arrow{ur} \arrow{dr} \\
  \arrow{r} & E_{n+1} \arrow{ur} & &  D_n \arrow{r} & E_n \arrow{ur} & & D_{n-1} \arrow{r} & {}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry about not posting the complete code. I will know from now on to do this.

Comment: @akgjh I made it worse by posting a misleading request so it is probably more my fault than yours. I could see later by your edit that you tried to do it. I just put it wrongly. (I thought your diagram just looked wrong - I didn't realise you had compilation errors. And 'make it compilable' is often clearer than 'minimally complete it' ;).) I'm sorry to have been confusing.